# Is it possible to customize the apprequest notification message similar to BranchOut?

Tags: facebook, apprequests

I've noticed that BranchOut requests have a custom notification message and stand apart from other app requests in my notifications.

Is this because BranchOut has a special partnership with Facebook?

The documentation states that the "message" value will not be displayed in the notification, so I'm curious how this is being done.

Answer (score 1):

it's definitely possible, using the parameter *new_style_message* set to **true** - you can double check this by reverse engineering their Javascript API library.

This is a sample code

```
FB.ui({
    display: 'iframe',
    method: 'apprequests',
    new_style_message: true,
    title: "Join my network",
    message: "would like you to join his network",
    to: [list of user ids to invite]
});
```

Answer (score 1):

No it is not possible even with new_style_apprequest parameter in FB.ui options. This used to work earlier but it has stopped working lately. It was anyways an undocumented feature. This is my guess that you might require special permissions from Facebook to be able to achieve this.